# how to create a query in hive for particular data

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using hive to load a data file and run hadoop mapreduce on it. But I am stuck at create table query. I have a data like this 59.7*, 58.9* where * is just a character. I want to make two columns to store 59.7 & 58.9. Can anyone help on that? Thanks

Comment: i don knw the exact syntax, i have tried: create table mydata(max DOUBLE, min DOUBLE) PARTITIONED BY (ds DOUBLE); that wont get rid of *.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RegexSerDe](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.java) to do that. You can visit this [page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/emr/getting-started-emr-load-data.html) if you need an example.